# Question about using a pattern in ReplacePart

Tags: pattern-matching

I noticed that "ReplacePart" can use pattern. For example:

```
ReplacePart[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {i_, i_} -> x]
{{x, 0, 0}, {0, x, 0}, {0, 0, x}}
```

So I naively think I can do a little change like

```
ReplacePart[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {i_+1, i_} -> x]
```

But it gives

```
{x, x, x}
```

Why? I anticipated that the result whould be

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {x,0,0}, {0, x, 0}}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you may have found a bug in `ReplacePart`.

Answer (score 13):

Use a `Condition` (`/;`) to check the relation between the values of the pattern elements. You must also use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`), since the rule now depends on the particular values of the matched pattern.

```
ReplacePart[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {i_, j_} :> 
  x /; i == j + 1]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 0}, {0, x, 0}} *)
```

UPDATE: The erroneous-appearing result of the original code appears to be due to `ReplacePart` checking the second argument to see if it is a list of parts to be replaced. If the first element of the list has depth (e.g. `{1}` or `_+1`), then `ReplacePart` treats all elements of the list as parts to be replaced.

Consider:

```
(* Expected use *)
ReplacePart[Array[f, {3, 3}], {{1}, {2}, {0}} -> x]
(* x[x, x, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2], f[3, 3]}] *)

(* First element is nonsense *)
ReplacePart[Array[f, {3, 3}], {_+1, 1, 2, 0} -> x]
(* x[x, x, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2], f[3, 3]}] *)

(* First element doesn't exist *)
ReplacePart[Array[f, {3, 3}], {{7}, 1, 2, 0} -> x]
(* x[x, x, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2], f[3, 3]}] *)
```

SECOND EDIT: So to analyze the original case, the first element of the replacement-part list has nontrivial depth, so we treat each element as a part to be replaced. The first element is nonsense, so it matches nothing. The second element is a `Blank`, so it matches all integers and all parts of the list are replaced by `x`.

Comment: can you also explain why the op got `{x,x,x}` in his approach? I can't make sense of that return value...

Comment: +1 although I think you don't necessarily need a delayed rule here as long as you constrain the pattern appropriately: `ReplacePart[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0}}, {i_, j_} /; (i == j + 1) -> x]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So what about this: ReplacePart[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {i_, i_ + 1} -> x]  gives {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}.  Can I understand it as when Mathematica scan the pattern list towards i_+1, and find that it is  neither a pattern  nor the first element, So Mathematica just quit and do nothing??

Comment: @matheorem `ReplacePart` examines the first item, which has trivial depth; therefore, it treats the list as a single position to be replaced. At least one element of the list is nonsense, therefore nothing is matched and nothing is replaced.

Comment: @Xerxes then what about ReplacePart[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {i_ + 1, i_, i_} -> x], it gives {x, x, x} . Ignoring the first nonsense element, the pattern shoud read as {i_,i_}->x, right? If so the result is unreasonable.

Comment: @matheorem No, it reads as `i_`, which replaces all parts with `x`, and then as `i_`, which replaces all parts with `x` again.

Comment: @Xerxes OK, I understand. You're right

Answer (score 6):

I think a possible explanation is that when an element of the part specification passes some preliminary test but then fails to resolve to something meaningful it is removed from the list mid-process.  For example:

```
m = Range@9 ~Partition~ 3;
r = {1, 2, 3};
x =.

ReplacePart[m, {i_ + 1, #} -> x] & /@ r // Column
ReplacePart[m, {_ + "bad", #} -> x] & /@ r // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the same behavior as:

```
ReplacePart[m, {#} -> x] & /@ r // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the first element of the specification does not contain a pattern nothing is replaced:

```
ReplacePart[m, {"bad", #} -> x] & /@ r // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I brought this to the attention of WRI's tech support. This is their response:

> This behavior is due to the way ReplacePart processes the part position
>   specifications given to it. When a part position specification cannot
>   structurally match a part position, behavior of ReplacePart is technically
>   undefined, though the proposed explanation at the MSE post to which you
>   implicitly refer is roughly accurate. In this case, ReplacePart does end up
>   treating each part position spec as an entire part spec due to the
>   ambiguity of the first part position spec.
>
> To avoid behavior like this, you can simply use Condition (/;) to enforce
>   relationships between part position specs.
>
> On your behalf, I've filed a suggestion with our development team to
>   improve documentation on this aspect of ReplacePart behavior.

It nice to know that they are looking-in at what goes on here and that they accept Mr. Wizards analysis as "roughly accurate".