# What's wrong with my rule?

Tags: replacement, sparse-arrays

Consider a simple code to form a SparseArray:

```
Q = 5;
a = Table[i, {i, Q}];
SparseArray[{{j_} /; j > 2 -> a[[j]]}, {Q}]
```

> Part::pspec: Part specification j is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

What is wrong with the rule? It seems I can not address any matrix element without getting such a warning. Sorry for such a minor question.

Comment: Use RuleDelayed (:>) instead of Rule (->)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But why?

Comment: Because you've to "wait" until each `j` is instantiated to be able to evaluate `a[[j]]`

Comment: Also covered here: [(18487)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487)
[(20736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20736)
[(25652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25652)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Belisarius says in a comment, using[`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) (:>) instead of[`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) (->) will fix your code.

```
Q = 5;
a = Table[i, {i, Q}];
SparseArray[{{j_} /; j > 2 :> a[[j]]}, {Q}]
```

> ```
> SparseArray[<3>, {5}]
> ```

```
Normal[%]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 3, 4, 5}
> ```